# Rails -- Getting hash response from HTTP request (readability url)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, httpwebrequest, readability

I'm having a little trouble using Readability - I tried using the `ruby-readability` gem and following the [instructions on GitHub](https://github.com/iterationlabs/ruby-readability) but the site I am trying to use it on is causing character encoding problems (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDMA).

Then I tried using the actual readability website: http://www.readability.com/api/content/v1/parser?url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDMA&token=*my_token_here* and it returned a page with the following information:

[image]

Ideal Answer: Step-by-Step: How to use ruby-readability gem to read this website in particular (it works for other websites)

Secondary Answer: How to access `params[:content]` for that site (in the pic is displays the value of content, which is what I want).

If you need me to clarify any part of the question please let me know!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Used examples from https://github.com/iterationlabs/ruby-readability

Make sure the gem is installed and required in your Gemfile. Then, from what it looks like you're trying to do:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'readability'
require 'open-uri'

# 1. Fetch the content of the site. open() requests the document
# and read() passes you the page content.
source = open('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDMA').read

# 2. Pass the content to the Readability gem to do its magic.
puts Readability::Document.new(source).content
```

Comment: I tried that and then the #2 step is what gave me a character encoding issue.